# Updating in Pipenv

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I have a problem regarding pipenv. Maybe it is only my understanding, but we will see. I have a project that uses python 3.7 and Django 2.1. Now the latest version of Django is 3.0.5.

I now want to update my Django version, but I have no idea how. `pipenv update` does nothing it only tells me that my requirements are already met. Even uninstalling Django an reinstalling it, does not update the version. I have no idea, how to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade the version of django you're using?

Comment: Yes, that is right!

Comment: Do you have a python environment already setup? You could try `pip install --upgrade django`

Comment: Yes there is a python environment. I have activated it through `pipenv shell`. I am trying to use pipenv here, otherwise my pipfile will not be up to date right?

Comment: You should update the version you want in your pipfile (specifying > 3.0 for example) then update.